# Bivariate power series as rational function

Tags: co.combinatorics, power-series

Suppose we have a bivariate power series of the form
$$\sum_{i}\sum_j a_{i,j} t^i s^j,$$
where for every fixed value of $i$ the corresponding univariate power series in $s$ is a rational function. Are there criteria to decide, when the whole (i.e., bivariate) series can be written as a rational function?

Comment: Each rational function has zero order. This implies  necessary conditions on coefficients $a_{i,j}$.

Comment: Do you know to what extent the usual theory of univariate rational generating functions carries over to the case where  the series coefficients are functions (say, univariate rational)? Do you still have a linerar recurrence relation?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik of course you have a finite linear recurrence relation (over any field, to say the least).

Comment: I was referring to Thm 4.1.1 in Stanley's book http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf
(some parts of the proof of it use the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed).

Comment: The condition " for every fixed value o f$ i$ the corresponding univariate power series in $s$ is a rational function" is not sufficient to this end as the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac 1 {1-\exp(t)s}$ shows.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik equivalence of (i) and (ii) in this theorem does not use that the field is algebraically close, you use it only for factorizing the denominator onto linear factors.